# Rails; is_hoge column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby/RoR, we often use `active?` method to validate things.
In DB, I use `is_` prefix for Boolean type.

So I just use `is_active` and get the result.

But I just  wonder I should wrap `is_active` with `active?` method in RoR.
What do you think about it?